# Store pointers to an object in map

Tags: c++, pointers, object, dictionary

I have a vector pointer that points to a `vector<object>` so 
`const std::vector<object> vecPtr* = &vec;`

Now i'd like to fill in this manner `std::multimap<std::string, object*> dataMap;` where the `key` is `object.name` and `value` is `pointer to an object`.

I tried

```
for(std::vector<object>::const_iterator it = data->cbegin(); it != data->cend(); ++it){
        dataMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, object*>(it->name, &it));
}
```

but i get an error.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, object*>::pair(const string&, std::vector<object>::const_iterator*)'
         dataMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, object*>(it->name, &it));
                                                                          ^
```

What am i doing wrong?

I know i complicating my life with pointers, but I want to avoid copying objects

Comment: You should mention exactly what the error you get is.

Comment: This looks fishy. You pass a pointer to an iterator. 'dataMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, object*>(it->name, &it))*

Comment: You actually add the address of the iterator to the map, not the pointer to the object.

Comment: @Oncaphillis so i should add a * at the end?

Comment: `vecPtr` is not declared as a pointer, and anyway it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the rest of the question.

Comment: @interjay ups, forgot to add a *, but that is not the reason for the error

Comment: @user2202368 No I assume your class CountryStat which you do not describe has a field value which is a pointer to object. Then  it should be it->value. If value is a member of CountryStat it should be &it->value. But beware of manipulating the vector in the latter case since your pointer to value would be a moving target.

Comment: @Oncaphillis CountryStat(now changed to "object") are stored inside a `vec`, each object has a .name variable. I have a problem when i want to copy a pointer to an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&it` is a pointer to iterator, not to an object. If you want to get a pointer to an object, write `&*it`.

After that you'll see an error saying that you can't convert from `const object*` to `object*` - this is because you are using `const_iterator`. So, depending on what you need, you can do two things.

Either declare `dataMap` as `std::multimap<std::string, const object*> dataMap;`, if you are not planning to change the objects in it.

Or use `iterator`:

```
for (std::vector<object>::iterator it = data->begin(); it != data->end(); ++it) {
    dataMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, object*>(it->name, &*it));
}
```

By the way, this loop can be rewritten as:

```
for (auto& a : *data) {
    dataMap.insert({a.name, &a});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid copying objects consider to use reference of objects. Moreover, consider to use shared pointer such as std::shared_ptr (for C++11), or boost::shared_ptr. A good style is to avoid allocating memory manually. Let's do it in an automatic way provided by the STL.

```
class Object{};
typedef boost::shared_ptr < Object > ObjectPtr;
```

then

```
std::multimap < std::string, ObjectPtr > map;
```

Creating instances of Object just use:

```
ObjectPtr obj = boost::make_shared < Object > ();
```

Comment: Smart pointers sound useful, but i haven't learned about them yet :/